# How to replace components inside parent component

Tags: angular

I've got a search form with results of searching. I can enter a single search result and view it's details, then I can go back to the list of results. How can I persist data on the search form, while changing the results/details component? Search is a separate component, which is displayed at the side of the screen while other components are interchanged. Details/list are also a separate components. Route with search is "/search" and route which is activated after entering details is like "/search/:id". What is a best practice to do such a thing?

Comment: Use service. Keep search data in service and subscribe to it in component where you'd like to show it. You can find small tutorial on angular official documentation https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4 .

Comment: I am already using such a solution to pass data from search details back to search list, but is it a cleanest solution? I feel like there should be a better way do replace components within a parents context

Comment: well, if you're not using state management (eg. NGRX), in that case this is good the way to go if you ask me. As long as this service is singleton in your module (lazy loaded preferably) and you have control over it. Serves single purpose and have it well organized, you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using seperate pages then you can use state management of ngRx(Redux). There you can handle you states of search functionality very clearly. But using ngRx involves lots of work so its not compulsory if you are working on a small app.

If you are making small application then you can use services.

if your both components are displaying on same view like left side you have search component and in right side if you are having list component then you can use @output and @Input event listeners.

Also you can use Subject of RxJS liabrary to work with events and state managements.